# Print a PDF in C# with non standard size on a label printer

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, dymo

I create a PDF in a C# web application containing a label that has to be printed on a [Dymo LabelWriter 450](http://global.dymo.com/itIT/Products/LabelWriter_450.html).

To create and print the label I am using [Spire.PDF](http://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/pdf-for-net-introduce.html#.Vt24dPnhDIU).

If I save the PDF in a folder and then print it using Acrobat Reader, it is printed correctly (and so I can confirm the page size set in my application is correct).

When I print directly from the application, the PDF is stretched abnormally, with reduced width and enlarged height, going beyond the boundaries of the label.

My code looks as follows:

```
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
doc.LoadFromFile(fileName);

SizeF pageSize = doc.Pages[0].Size;

PageSettings ps = new PageSettings();
ps.PaperSize = new PaperSize("MyPaperSize", (int)pageSize.Width, (int)pageSize.Height);

doc.PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings = ps;

doc.PrinterName = printerName;

doc.PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = 0;
doc.PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = 0;
doc.PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = 0;
doc.PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom = 0;

PrintDocument printDoc = doc.PrintDocument;
printDoc.Print();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally ended up using [PdfiumViewer](https://github.com/pvginkel/PdfiumViewer) to open my document and create a PrintDocument to send to the printer.

The following code now prints correctly on my Dymo printer

```
PrinterSettings printerSettings = new PrinterSettings();
printerSettings.PrinterName = printerName;
printerSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize;
printerSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
printerSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);

PdfiumViewer.PdfDocument pdfiumDoc = PdfiumViewer.PdfDocument.Load(fileName);
PrintDocument pd = pdfiumDoc.CreatePrintDocument(PdfiumViewer.PdfPrintMode.CutMargin);             
pd.PrinterSettings = printerSettings;
pd.Print();
```

I suppose the problem with the document being loaded by Spire.Pdf is that the `DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea` (read only) has the wrong size and so the document eventually is compressed in that area.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by saving a copy of the file on my server. If I "save" the document before printing it, it prints correctly, even if I print from the same C# object, without touching my newly created file.

```
document.SaveToFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(string.Format(@".\my-ticket-{0}-{1}.pdf", DateTime.Now.Ticks, Ticket.OrderNumber)));
PrintDocument printDoc = document.PrintDocument;
printDoc.Print();
```